# Python: recreate union and intersect of 2 lists with basic tools

Tags: python, list, union, intersect

I have to recreate the 2 pythons functions "a.union(b)" and a.intersect(b) with only with the tools

append; pop; len;while; for i in range; if-else; l[i] (for a list l); and booleens

And to have at the end a function with 2 lists as argument and to return the final ordonned list.
For example

a=[1.2.5.6]

b=[3.5.6.8.15]

if i enter f(a,b) and get in return [1.2.3.5.6.8.15] (union)
and if i enter g(a,b) i get something like [5.6]

I tried to do it by comparing the list terms successively but in that case if one list is shorter it will be emptied before the 1other and i will be comparing a number with nothing. I tried to use while but I can only check if the list is emptied for one and not both.

Please if you could help me :s

Ps: Not beeing english i hope you'll pass on the language mistakes I did.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that the two input lists are sorted, then this is just the merge step of mergesort.  For that, you need two indices, i and j, and you move one of them forward at a time, not both.  Start them out at 0.  When one of them hits the end of its list, you need two while loops - one that takes values from the first list until exhausted, and another that takes values form the second list until exhausted.